# Only first time, in IE11, textarea placeholder text does not disappear on focus/typing

Tags: angularjs, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Could you please help in below mentioned issue in IE11.

Only first time when on focus/type in a textarea, the placeholder text does not disappear. But from 2nd time it behaves normally i.e. placeholder text disappears on focus/type.

I have used Boootstrap 3.3.5 and angular in my project.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmf1784j/1/

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 zeroResultFeedbackContainer">
        <h5 class="zeroTextMedium">Feedback</h5>
        <textarea id="feedbackFunctionBox" class="form-control" placeholder="What did you expect to find?"></textarea>            
    </div
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting any problems with your code in IE11 on Windows 7. Different browsers handle placeholder text differently, e.g. Chrome doesn't remove the text until you start typing. Perhaps this is a bug in the particular version of IE11 you are running?

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for your comment. Yes, you are right. But whenever you include angular package, the issue will be appear in IE11 only.